# Как разместить компонент в неклинтской части окна?

Tags: delphi

неужели никто незнает?

например как это делает компонент ribbon controls в delphi xe
или alpha controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предыдущие ораторы не вполне правы. Они предлагают способ размещения компонента за пределами видимой части окна или в окне без заголовка.

На самом деле подобные вещи (рисование компонент, наползающих на границы окна и заголовок) реализуется обработкой сообщений [`WM_NCPAINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145212(v=vs.85).aspx) и [`WM_PAINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145213(v=vs.85).aspx). Отправной точкой вам, конечно, послужит [MSDN - Nonclient Area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162743(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Можно прибегнуть к хитрости

Создай дополнительную форму, укажи в ее параметрах:

```
BordesStyle: bsNone
```

Поставь на форму, например, кнопку, в верхний левый угол. И уменьши форму под размер кнопки.

В событии OnPaint основной формы укажи:

```
Form2.Left:= Form1.Left;
Form2.Top:= Form1.Top;
```

В итоге получится кнопка, как в опере.

Answer (score 0):

раздвигай окно, туда ставь компонент, задвигай окно обратно.

используй панель на всю рабочую поверхность, а под панель положи нужный компонент.

у компонента visible := false;